# How do I get rid of the black lines in my ground plane texture?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, procedural, reflection

[image: Current Render Situation]

this is my current eevee render I just want my render to look like this one below

[image: The Render I want]

Nodes for the ground plane:

[image: Shader Nodes]

The Blender file: [Blender file](https://pasteall.org/blend/6021f3bc44a748c2bc3e7be6db39d266)

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I've added the file, thanks

Comment: You need to edit your post and put the link to that pasteall into your post so we can see it too.

Comment: oh right!, apologies, very new here

Comment: it looks like it's caused by the Displacement, I thought this node only worked in Cycles no?

Comment: so the creator pointed to his old video where he uses this node in cycles and says he has used the same, although the result is completely different. Should I completely remove the displacement? and what should be the new node setup?

Comment: yes it works in Cycles but probably not in Eevee. If you want the same effect you can use the Noise Texture for example, I can try a setup if you want

Comment: yes please, I just want to get rid of those black lines and have water type reflections for my ground plane

Answer (score 1):

From what I know the *Displacement* node doesn't work in Eevee so it may be just a kind of buggy artefact. There are many ways to make water:

You can plug a *Musgrave Texture* into a (*Vector) Bump* into the *Glossy* node to fake real 3D. To animate, keyframe the *W* value or the *Mapping* location values:

[image]

[image]

If you want real displacement you need to subdivide your plane and give it a *Displace* modifier with a *Clouds* texture that you animate with an empty (in the modifier choose *Coordinate > Object, Object > Empty*):

[image]

Of course you can combine the solutions.